# Images in SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a GUI with a database attached, my SQL table is :

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imagerecord (
    PId int,
    PName varchar(50) not null,
    Photo varbinary(max)
    )
```

Clearly I am trying to include an image in the database (atleast, that's what I think I'm doing), however my system is not identifying the 'varbinary' datatype, showing this error :

```
    Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'max) )' at line 4
```

Please tell me what to do, is there some extra software do I have to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing Microsoft SQL Server syntax for `VARBINARY(MAX)` with MySQL syntax for `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. Neither RDBMS implementation supports both of these features.

- Microsoft SQL Server supports `MAX` as a length instead of a specific number, but standard SQL and most other brands don't support this option.
- MySQL supports `IF NOT EXISTS` as an optional modifier, but this is also not standard SQL, and Microsoft doesn't support this extension.

You need to figure out which brand you're using. The fact that `MAX` gave an error but `IF NOT EXISTS` did not suggests you are using MySQL. Here are links to the respective documentation pages:

Microsoft SQL Server 2012:

- [CREATE TABLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)
- [BINARY and VARBINARY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)

MySQL 5.6:

- [CREATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html)
- [BINARY and VARBINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-varbinary.html)

The maximum length of a VARBINARY in MySQL is 65535. If you need a column that can accept a longer string, you can use MEDIUMBLOB which allows up to 16MB, or LONGBLOB which allows up to 4GB.